# xmlHttpRequest Cannot make any requests from null in the javascript console

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I've been searching around on stack exchange and online in general and while I can find a lot of answers similar to what I'm looking for, I can't find an exact answer.

I'm learning about requesting and parsing XML data via javascript and I'm running into the error "Cannot make any requests from null."

I saved an XML rss feed to my local computer, opened it in chrome, pulled up the javascript console, and tried the following to start working with the data:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://cs.dev/scraps/engadget_rss_feed.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
var xml = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

It all works fine until i get to the send statement. When I execute it I get the error message noted above. The full error text is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cs.dev/engadget_rss_feed.xml. Cannot make any requests from null. Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

I read up on how you can't request the xml from a domain outside of the server you're running the js from so I thought moving it to my local web server would fix it.

I also tried the same open method using my home Sites folder url without the virtual domain and still get the error.

Is there something I'm missing here? Can I not run this line by line in the javascript console?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a Chrome issue.

See: 
[this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-apps/-zUIYNaKqDM/xnDfhPB7i6AJ)